# How to use Get.resource("path") REST APIs using Serenity Screenplay with HTTPS Validation as an Actor

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I'm new in Serenity BDD and I'm trying to use `Get.resource()` method as an Actor for API Test but I need to turn off the SSL validation, could you please help me on that?

```
 tom.attemptsTo(
        Get.resource("/today")
);
```

Thanks a lot